# twitter rest api media entity

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am using Twitter's REST API to get the status of a specific tweet:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=210462857140252672&include_entities=true
```

However the resulting json does not include the media entity at the response as described in https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects

I have also tried with java, using twitter4j.

Answer (score 0):

Fiugured that out. It had to do with the list of tweets themselves. By fetching more tweets in the list, some of them inluded the media entities with the images in the returned json.